# Can't remove Rails under Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.1

The system returns rails 2.3.5 responding to `rails -v`. However it returns "rails not installed" for `gem uninstall rails`.

The system returns error for `gem install rails`:

```
@ubuntu:~$ gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::DependencyError)
    Unable to resolve dependencies: rails requires activesupport (= 3.1.1), actionpack (= 3.1.1), activerecord (= 3.1.1), activeresource (= 3.1.1), actionmailer (= 3.1.1), railties (= 3.1.1), bundler (~> 1.0)
```

Any idea about the problem?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get remove rails
```

Also, use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/). It allows you to install gems in your user directory, thus eliminating the need to use `sudo` (and thus putting yourself at risk).

Comment: How to install rails 3.1? Does apt-get intall only install from the ubuntu repo (currently rails 2.3.5)? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it installs the version in the repo, which is currently 2.3.5. Ubuntu's policy is to only push security updates once an Ubuntu release is final, so they'll never upgrade the version of a package (it will always be 2.3.5 for your release, only the patchlevel may increase). You can probably find some PPAs that offer a more recent version of rails, but I think RVM is still the best solution.

Comment: Installed the rvm and run 'gem install rails'. The error message is exactly the same. Still has dependency error. Is bundler going to help here?

Comment: After installing rvm install a ruby version in it (i.e. `rvm install 1.9.2`) and switch to it (`rvm use 1.9.2`). Create a new gemset (`rvm gemset create my-gemset`) and switch to it (`rvm gemset use my-gemset`). **Then** install rails (`gem install rails`). Do not use `sudo` for any of these commands. After all that you'll have to type in both `use` commands every time you start a new session. To avoid that, write a [rvmrc](http://beginrescueend.com/workflow/rvmrc/) file.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get remove rails rails-ruby1.8 -y
```

after getting root privileges

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to remove it using the Ubuntu built in package manager. Try apt-get remove and look into this page https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RubyOnRails